# Vector and parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\vec a= (-3,5,3)$ and $\vec b=(7,-4,2)$. Express in vector and parametric form, the line through these points.

Would the first step be finding the cross product?

Thank you so much

Comment: To write the vector or parametric form of a line, you need to know a point on the line and a vector parallel to the line.  The cross product doesn't give you either.

Comment: are These vectors or Points?

Comment: $P(t)=a+t(b-a)$

Comment: They’re vectors!

Comment: Then what do you mean with "the line through these **points**."

Comment: I don’t know that’s just what the question says

Comment: The points are being described by their position vectors relative to the normal basis presumably.

Answer (score 0):

I think your $a$ and $b$ are points here, so to get a line you can start with one point, $a$, the vector from $a$ to $b$ is $b-a$. (so if you take $b$ you need $a-b$). Now you can define your line in two ways: $q_1(t) = a+t(b-a)$ or $q_2(t) = b+t(a-b)$.